# Drools Rules Template - first invocation 1000 times slower than subsequence invocations

Tags: java, tomcat, drools, rule-engine

I have built a [Drools Rules Template](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.4.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e6300) using Drools 6.4.0.Final

It is pretty much identical to the example provided [here](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/master/drools-examples/src/main/java/org/drools/examples/decisiontable/PricingRuleTemplateExample.java).

I have wrapped it in a `Spring` `RestController` and deployed it as a WAR in to `Tomcat`.

I notice that the first call is always very slow to get a result and gets slower as the number of rows in the `xls` spreadsheet grows.

I imagine drools builds an index when the first ever `KieSession` is created. And that this index is subsequently cached making further calls much faster?

I see the same behaviour when invoking directly from unit tests. First test is slow and subsequent tests are 1000 times faster.

For example, I see first call take 30secs and every subsequent call take 20ms where the spreadsheet has ~1000 rows.

Is there a way to force this "indexing" step to happen when the web application server (`Tomcat`) is starting up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the example you have linked, there is a line that is doing more than what it appears to be doing. The line I'm talking about is:

```
KieSession ksession = kc.newKieSession( "DTableWithTemplateKS" );
```

One of the steps inside `KieContainer.newKieSession()` is to [create the `KieBase`](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/master/drools-compiler/src/main/java/org/drools/compiler/kie/builder/impl/KieContainerImpl.java#L605) the specified `KieSession` belongs to. A `KieBase` is the binary representation of your rules. Once a `KieBase` is built, it can be used to spawn multiple `KieSessions` (their runtime counterpart). The creation of a `KieBase` could be very time consuming. Spawning new `KieSessions` from it it is not.

The `KieContainer` class uses an [internal Map](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/master/drools-compiler/src/main/java/org/drools/compiler/kie/builder/impl/KieContainerImpl.java#L441) to keep a reference to the `KieBases` that were already built. The first time you ask `KieContainer` for a `KieSession` the `KieContainer` has first to build the `KieBase`. Following invocations of `newKieSession()` will reuse the KieBase already built. Note that this is true as long as you always ask for the same `KieSession`. Try having multiple `KieBases` and ask for different `KieSessions` from them and you will see that the first time you ask for a `KieSession` from a new `KieBase` you will experience this delay.

One thing you could do is to ask `KieContainer` for your `KieBase` when your app is starting. You can do this by either executing `kc.newKieSession( "XXX" );` or `kc.getKieBase("YYY");`

Hope it helps,

Comment: Your suggestion of calling kc.newKieSession( "XXX" ) when creating my Spring bean during startup worked as hoped. Thank you.

@Bean
    public KieContainer kieContainer() {
        KieContainer kieContainer =    KieServices.Factory.get().getKieClasspathContainer();
        kieContainer.newKieSession("QuestionsKS");
        return kieContainer;
    }

Comment: What if I have Drools running on Lambda, behind an API gateway in AWS?  This means I am required to start a new KieSession/KieBase every time the Lambda is invoked/API is hit.

If I keep the Lambda warm, I do not see the delay, but 3 years after this question was first asked, are there any better alternatives built into Drools?

Comment: Take a look at kogito: https://kogito.kie.org/ . This is supposed to be the cloud native version of Drools/JBPM.