# Drools Initial Invocation slow compared to subsequent executions

Tags: performance, initialization, drools

We are using Drools 6.4.0.Final (but have tried 7.12.0.Final with the same results) as our rules engine and have noticed quite a significant difference in response time on the first call KieSession.execute vs. any subsequent executions i.e. 200-300ms vs. <1ms thereafter.

We are loading all our rules on startup by building and loading the knowledge bases once upfront and only creating the stateless session per rule invocation. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247847/drools-rules-template-first-invocation-1000-times-slower-than-subsequence-invo), I have added invocation of  kc.newStatelessKieSession() and kc.getKieBase() as part of the rule startup with an insignificant improvement as a result. The only solution I have found so far is to execute the rules atleast once on startup with dummy input so that all actual executions are always fast.

I've looked at the performance test in the [drools examples](http://githubcom/kiegroup/drools/tree/master/drools-examples/src/main/java/org/drools/examples/performance) and see that here they call the rules once first before timing the actual subsequent rules. Is this standard / to avoid this initial load skewing the performance results?

Is there better way that I could avoid this initial delay by forcing the rules to be initialised on startup rather than doing this as part of the first call?

Comment: Did you find any solutions?